# $(\exists \lambda - eigenvalue, \lambda=0) \Leftrightarrow ? (\alpha = -1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, mathematical-physics

> $\left\{
> \begin{aligned}
> -u''=\lambda u\\
> u(0)=u'(1)+\alpha u(1) =0\\
> \end{aligned}
> \right.$, on $[0,1]$ ;
>
> $(\exists \lambda \text{ eigenvalue}, \lambda=0) \Leftrightarrow \alpha = -1$ 
> $\lambda$ should be eigenvalue of differential operator u↦−u′′
> with domain being the space of twice differentiable functions on [0,1]
> satisfying the given boundary conditions for some fixed α

$u(x) = A \cos(\sqrt\lambda x) + B \sin(\lambda x)$

$u(0) = 0 \Rightarrow A=0.$

$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
u'(x) = B\sqrt\lambda \cos(\sqrt\lambda x) \\
u'(1)+\alpha u(1) =0\\
\end{aligned}
\right.$

$B\sqrt\lambda \cos(\sqrt\lambda)-\alpha B \sin(\sqrt\lambda) =0$

Let $\lambda\neq 0 \Rightarrow \operatorname{ctg}(\sqrt \lambda)=-\alpha$ solution $\forall \alpha\neq0.$

Let $\lambda= 0 \Rightarrow u''=0, u(x) = D + Cx, u(0)=0, \Rightarrow D=0, u'(1)+\alpha u(1)=0, \Rightarrow c(1+\alpha)=0,$ in this way if $\alpha\neq-1,$ then $c=0$, what gives a trivial solution $u(x)$.
If $\alpha = 1, c$ any, then there exists a non-trivial solution. $\square$

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. I suggest you use English. Mathematical symbols are useful, but require context written in natural language to get the meaning across.

Comment: I'm trying to solve the exercise, but I'm not sure how well I'm doing, so I'm looking for help on the forum. English is not my native language, I am not very good at explaining myself in it, I apologize if somewhere I get illiterate or not clear. I need to show that the eigenvalue $\lambda =0$ exists $\Leftrightarrow \alpha = -1$

Comment: Is the question then that there exists a non-trivial solution to $u'' = 0,\ u(0)=u'(1)+\alpha u(1) = 0,$ if and only if $\alpha = -1$?

Comment: If so, there is no need to overcomplicate with general solution to $-u'' = \lambda u$, you want to inspect the case of $\lambda = 0$ and as you wrote, $u'' = 0$ if and only if $u(x) = Ax+B$. Then, the boundary conditions become $B = (\alpha + 1)A = 0$. So, if there is a non-trivial solution, we have $B = 0$, so $A\neq 0$, and therefore $\alpha = -1$. And conversely, if $\alpha = -1$, verify that $u(x) = Ax$ is a non-trivial solution for all $A\neq 0$.

Comment: @MaximBokov The question cannot be answered without context. Eigenvalue of **what**? What is $\alpha$?

Comment: @5xum I'm guessing $\lambda$ should be eigenvalue of differential operator $u\mapsto -u''$ with domain being the space of twice differentiable functions on $[0,1]$ satisfying the given boundary conditions for some fixed $\alpha$, but it would be nice if OP confirmed that.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what im trying to say

Comment: Maxim, please edit your question including these details. In its current state it's getting closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze what's being asked. $\lambda = 0$ being eigenvalue is equivalent to saying that there is non-trivial solution $u$ to differential equation
\begin{align}
u'' &= 0\\
u(0) &= u'(1)+\alpha u(1) = 0 \tag{1}
\end{align}

So, you want to prove that there exists non-trivial solution $u$ of $(1)$ if and only if $\alpha = -1$. Therefore, the first part of your solution is completely redundant (and incomprehensible to me). You shouldn't care about general solutions to $-u'' = \lambda u$ for $\lambda \neq 0$.

Thus, the only relevant part is after you write "Let $\lambda = 0$." Then you conclude that $u(x) = D + Cx$. Here you skipped some things that should be written in interest of clear communication, I would write something like this:

> Assume that $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue. That means that there exists non-trivial solution $u$ of $(1)$. Since $u'' = 0$, we conclude that $u$ is of the form $u(x) = D + Cx$ for some constants $C,D$, such that not both $C$ and $D$ are $0$.

What you then do is write the boundary conditions of $(1)$ in terms of $C$ and $D$, a correct step: $D = (\alpha +1)C = 0$. You then argue that if $\alpha \neq -1$, this would imply that $C = 0$ and therefore $u = 0$, which is contradiction with the assumption that $u$ was non-trivial. This is fine, but I'd write it directly:

> Since $D = 0$ from the boundary conditions and $u$ is non-trivial, we have $C \neq 0$. Therefore, $(\alpha + 1)C = 0$ implies that $\alpha + 1 = 0$, i.e. $\alpha _= -1$.

This finishes one implication and we need to prove the converse. You write "If $\alpha=1,c$ any, then there exists a non-trivial solution." I'll assume that $\alpha = 1$ is a typo, it should say $\alpha = -1$. However, "$c$ any" is a genuine mistake, it should be $C\neq 0$. Then you say it gives a non-trivial solution, but you don't write that solution or verify that it is solution. So, you need to write something like this:

> Assume that $\alpha = -1$ and define $u(x) = Cx$ for $C\neq 0$. Then $u'' = 0$ and $u(0) = 0$, $u'(1) + \alpha u(1) = C - C = 0$, so $u$ is a non-trivial solution to $(1)$, and therefore $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue.